# Validation failed: Class must exist even though object exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Fairly new to Rails. I'm having trouble saving an object and its association. It seems to be because of the default validation rule around association. When I forcefully turn the validation off, object is created properly along with association. Would love to understand what I"m doing wrong. Thanks!

Error:
[ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in OrdersController#create
Validation failed: Portfolios must exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uofVs.png)

Below is my relevant code

ordes_controller.rb

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_portfolio
  before_action :set_order, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy ]

  def create
    @order = @portfolio.orders.build(order_params)
    @position = Position.find_by_symbol(order_params[:symbol])

    if @position == nil
      @position = @portfolio.positions.create(symbol: order_params[:symbol])
      @order.position_id = @position.id
    else
      @order.position_id = @position.id
    end

    logger.debug("****position: #{@position.inspect}")
    logger.debug("****order: #{@order.inspect}")
    logger.debug("****portfolio: #{@portfolio.inspect}")

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save!
        format.html { redirect_to portfolio_order_path(@portfolio, @order), notice: "Order was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_portfolio
      @portfolio = Portfolio.find(params[:portfolio_id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:order_date, :order_type, :order_source, :symbol, :price, :shares, :fees, :total, :portfolio_id, :position_id)
    end
```

orders.rb
I don't have any explicit validation declared

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :portfolios
  belongs_to :position
end
```

for what its worth, everything saves properly, including the associations if i change the first line to

```
belongs_to :portfolios, optional: true
```

Below are the outputs of the 3 objects that I logged, as you can see, all the ids are present

```
****position: #<Position id: 1, symbol: "nio", name: nil, market_price: nil, percent_change: nil, shares: nil, avg_cost: nil, total_cost: nil, market_value: nil, total_return: nil, portfolio_id: 1, created_at: "2021-03-24 16:43:06.306210000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-03-24 16:43:06.306210000 +0000">
****order: #<Order id: nil, order_date: "2021-03-20", order_type: "sell", order_source: "robinhood", symbol: "nio", price: 40.0, shares: 100.0, fees: 0.0, total: 4000.0, position_id: 1, portfolio_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
****portfolio: #<Portfolio id: 1, name: "YZ Portfolio", description: "personal investment", currency: "USD", reinvest_dividend: true, privacy: "private", created_at: "2021-03-23 19:05:16.653605000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-03-23 19:05:36.772117000 +0000">
```

Comment: It should be `belongs_to :portfolio` probably

Comment: ah thanks yeah that worked! that was super dumb of me. Thanks for being the extra set of eyes